# DocumentDb query with multiple partitions using IList.Contains(partition)

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

Can Azure DocumentDB parallelize queries across partitions if the query filter uses the IList Contains method rather than explicitly ORing the partitions?

E.g.

```
DocumentClient client = ...
Uri documentUri = ...
FeedOptions = new FeedOptions { EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true };

IList<string> partitions = new List<string> { "x", "y", "z" };
Expression<Func<ResourceType, bool>> filter =
    (ResourceType rt) => partitions.Contains(rt.PartitionId);

IDocumentQuery<ResourceType> queryable =
    client.CreateDocumentQuery<ResourceType>(documentUri, feedOptions)
          .Where(filter)
          .AsDocumentQuery();
FeedResponse<ResourceType> response = await queryable.ExecuteNextAsync<ResourceType>();
```

Comment: Please read [Parallel query execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/tutorial-develop-documentdb-dotnet#parallel-query-execution) and try to specify the [MaxDegreeOfParallelism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.feedoptions.maxdegreeofparallelism?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=azure-dotnet#overloads) property.

Comment: Thanks. My question means to refer to the capacity of the SDK to convert the .Contains into parallel queries, assuming the MaxDegreeOfParallelism is properly set (which it wasn't).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Contains queries (translated to SQL `IN`) will be batched/parallelized to the matching partitions. Like @fred-han mentions, please set [FeedOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.feedoptions.maxdegreeofparallelism?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=azure-dotnet#overloads).